# How to create a list of items with fields in WordPress?

Tags: customization, custom-content

I'm new to WordPress and hoping some of you experts can help me figure out the best way to attack what seems like such a simple problem. I need to have two lists of items that the user can add to, delete and update that will show up on the home page of the site. Both lists will be variable in length. They will live on a static home page if that matters. The first list contains items that need to have two fields and the second list contains items that need to have three fields. Then I need to be able to loop through them to display them with CSS styling. If I can somehow get an array of these items, I can handle that part. I've read and read and read stuff, and the more I read, the more confused I'm getting on how best to do this. Custom post types? Taxonomies? Custom Fields? Some combination of those? If I was building this from scratch, this would be such a simple thing, but I can't figure out the best way to do this with WordPress? Can anyone give me some guidance?

Answer (score 2):

Try the pods CMS plugin: http://podscms.org

Comment: exactly what I was looking for! a simple way to make custom things. Now I have to find out how to easily display them or even show lists of them

Comment: @Flion, did you find anything? A year later with some googling I have the same problem.

Comment: @Lincoln Bergeson: yes just keep looking for "wordpress pods" + something, or read the pods documentation. eventually I figured out how to use them, and its quite handy. dont have a reference at hand sorry

Comment: I wonder what's the difference between pods and catalog.

Answer (score 1):

- [Custom Post Type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) is content item;
- [Custom Fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) are arbitrary (as opposed to standard and typical like title or content) entries of information, connected to post;
- [Taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies) is structure applied to content.

So the one of the possible ways to approach your setup would be:

- list item = custom post type;
- data that you need to be stored for list item = custom fields;
- which of the lists item belongs to = taxonomy (or also custom fields since you don't have many lists).